# Several points are marked on a line, and all possible segments are made between pairs of these points. One point lies on 80 segments, another 90......

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

**One of the points lies on 80 of these segments; another point lies on
90 segments. How many points were marked on the line?**

Answer Choices are 20, 22, 80, and 90

My work:
[image]

Comment: Where is your work?  Does being an endpoint count as lying on that segment?

Comment: Being an endpoint count as lying on the segment yes. I don't know how to approach this problem except finding a general formula for the number of segments a point is lying on. I tried the formula but it never gives me 80 and 90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result suggests that here an endpoint is not counted as lying on a segment.

When we assume this to be the case, we find that each point will lie on $ab$ segments, where there are $a$ points to one side and $b$ points to the other - in other words, the total number of points is $a+b+1$.

Looking then at the factors of $80$ and $90$, we can see that both can be produced by a partition of $21$: $80= 16\times 5$ and $90= 15\times 6$. This implies that the answer sought is $22$.

---

By contrast, if we assume that the endpoints do indeed lie on segments, each point lies on $ab+a+b = (a+1)(b+1)-1$ segments and we would be looking for suitable ways to factor $81$ and $91$, but this doesn't give an answer.

Comment: i love you broski, the answer is indeed 22 from the answer key. i get it now thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. If you find that this has fully answered your question, you can accept $\color{#0B2}\checkmark$ the answer; if your reputation increases you will be able to upvote any answer (on your or others' questions) that you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming being the endpoint (that is, one of the pre-selcted set of points) means to belong to a segment, there are two cases for any point: either it is an endpoint or not.

Suppose there are $N > 0$ points chosen.

If the point $P$ is *not* an endpoint and there are $m$ points to the left, then there are $N-m$ points to the right and $P$ belongs to $m\cdot (N-m)$ segments.

OTOH if $P$ *is* an endpoint and there are $m$ points to the left, then there are $(N-m-1$) points to the right and $P$ belong to $m\cdot (N-m-1)$ segments as an internal point and to $N-1$ segments as an endpoint (one to each of remaining $N-1$ points).

So, you need to find such number $N$, that there exist numbers $m_{80}$ and $m_{90}$ such that
$$m_{80}(N-m_{80}) = 80 \quad \text{or} \quad m_{80}(N-1-m_{80})+(N-1) = 80$$
and
$$m_{90}(N-m_{90}) = 90 \quad \text{or} \quad m_{90}(N-1-m_{90})+(N-1) = 90$$

But I have no idea how to do that efficiently. :(